# AutoCompleteTextView on click of item not set in AutoCompleteBox

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I want to show item in `AutoCompleteTextView`. Its working fine and all drop down item showing. but according to my need i dont want to set item in AutoComplete box on click of item. How can i achieve this?

```
public class AutoCompleteViewActvitiy extends Activity {
    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;
    String[] language;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

//after calling this service then you will get resposne ...in post method
        new CallServiceForFetchResponseOfCategory().execute();

    }


    public class CallServiceForFetchResponseOfCategory extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        public static final String REQUEST_METHOD = "GET";
        public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
        public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 15000;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String stringUrl = params[0];
            String result;
            String inputLine;

            try {
                URL myUrl = new URL(stringUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)
                        myUrl.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod(REQUEST_METHOD);
                connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                connection.connect();
                InputStreamReader streamReader = new
                        InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
                }
                reader.close();
                streamReader.close();
                result = stringBuilder.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                result = null;
            }

            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //in response you will get category array ....
            //like 
            then you will set array into this :
            language = .......;
            then
            setResponse();
        }

    }

    private void setResponse() {

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, language);
        //Getting the instance of AutoCompleteTextView
        autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView
        autoCompleteTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
// first srevice again and again call for fetching the result and show in autocomplete

                if (autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    new CallServiceForFetchResponseOfCategory().execute();

                }

            }
        });

autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

//according to id i will call this service but issue is that when i click on item it will set default in autocomplete text box and
        //again  afterTextChanged will call then again  CallServiceForFetchResponseOfCategory hit, that is the issue 
        // i dont want call this time CallServiceForFetchResponseOfCategory service when i click on item...
        new FetchingCityDataAsynkTask().execute();


    }
});
    }

//

    public class FetchingCityDataAsynkTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        public static final String REQUEST_METHOD = "GET";
        public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
        public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 15000;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String stringUrl = params[0];
            String result;
            String inputLine;

            try {
                URL myUrl = new URL(stringUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)
                        myUrl.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod(REQUEST_METHOD);
                connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                connection.connect();
                InputStreamReader streamReader = new
                        InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
                }
                reader.close();
                streamReader.close();
                result = stringBuilder.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                result = null;
            }

            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
      //setresponse here
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: i need only to show items like when we search item in website and dropdown list show

Comment: actually there are two different services for this first for autocomplete with textwatcher for getting dropdown list and on click of dropdown item other service will call for getting data

Comment: just think you are fetching city data from server and showing in dropdown view of autocomplete textview and service calling from textwatcher after text change listener. then after getting city in drop down you will click on item and get city data from server

Comment: but when you click on item it will set in autocomplete and then textwatcher will again call and then city service will called i think this should not happen we need to call fetch city data on click of item

Comment: on the place of TextWatcher  now i am using Filterable adapter which will call AsyncTask  for searching every text and set into AutocompleteTextView  but issue again same, when we click on AutoCompleteItem  it will default set into AutoCompleteTextView  and then again AsyncTask will call for searching item because filterable will call according to changing item in AutoCompleteTextView. this should not be happen,Filterable should not be call when i click on item

Comment: i try your code in POC . its working fine thanks for help . for immediate releasing i have to done with that but currently i am changing code with Filterable

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did in a project of mine. I simply put the text value of the `AutoCompleteTextView` to `""`

```
articlesAutocomplete.setOnItemClickListener(
            (detailedArticleAdapterView, childView, position, id) ->{
                DetailedArticle selectedArticle = (DetailedArticle)detailedArticleAdapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                /*logic with selected article*/
                articlesAutocomplete.setText("");
            }
    );
```

I hope this is what you wanted to achieve :)

EDIT : I saw in your comments that you use a TextWatcher, why do you use it for? It may change the usefulness of my solution ^^

Comment: textwatcher use for getting dropdown list item values. it will fetch from server

Comment: @pskink i need TextWatcher for fetching data from server just like this http://aqicn.org./api/

Comment: Ok my bad I didn't get what you wanted. Check @pskink's code it's the way you use an AutoCompleteTextView indeed. Please, next time would you mind share your code? It's a bit rough to understand without the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: sorry for late response my simple question is that , is  there any way to not set data in Appcompact box when click on item ?

Comment: You really should share the code, I don't understand if you are creating an AutocompleteTextview by yourself or if you're using the one provided by Android, in which cas @pskink's link is the way to go :/ and I can't figure out what is the `AppCompact box` you're talking of